Any sites that track/report primary radar?
Most (all?) web sites that display real-time tracking display ADS-B or Mode-S transponder data. But if an aircraft is not broadcasting, then only a 'skin paint' will be visible. I know that FAA radars return both transponder data AND raw radar RF energy returns.
Is anyone aware of any web sites or any public APIs that have access to Primary radar data from FAA radars to track  targets that are not squawking?

In the US at least, FR24 does use FAA radar data: https://www.flightradar24.com/how-it-works#faa

@jacron, can you help me navigate the FR24 site to replay historical data from 22 Apr?  So far I've been unable to figure out how to do that.

I’m on my mobile right now where I believe it’s not supported but check https://support.fr24.com/support/solutions/articles/3000120423-how-to-view-playback-on-the-flightradar24-website-

Thanks.   Will do that.
